# What to use to seal an exterior cable penetration in brick?

Tags: exterior, brick, caulking, cables

A Comcast tech came to our 3-unit building, ran a new cable into the utility room, and pulled out the seal that was there before, leaving it open as we're getting cold and wet for fall.

What should I fill this gap with? Is what was there before just some generic exterior silicone caulk? I'm wary to use polyurethane foam I don't want to "glue" everything shut, and caulk can kinda be removed without much destruction. I have some window/door/siding/trim caulk, but I don't know if there's something better to fill the giant gap (or just glob it in there...)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Duct seal. The stuff from the electrical aisle, not the stuff with a similar or identical name from the HVAC aisle.

A non-hardening putty for sealing electrical ducts (conduits, holes in the wall) against water and insects.

Usually gray. Removable and reusable. Comes as a "bar" or "brick" of putty in a plastic bag (at least when I've gotten it.)

Comment: I was looking at that, but the specs on it say it's "not for use outdoors" https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/44/44803494-803b-4281-9c76-5250672dabf9.pdf

Comment: We called it monkey sh!t the duct seal it works best if you roll it in your hands to warm it up, with a hole that large I would put a pull string with a piece of plastic like a bottle cap to pull it out in the future. Use nylon string not cotton cotton can wick water inside nylon won’t. I always have that for sealing penetrations between zones , small holes I use clear silicone but that is quite large for silicone.

Comment: The way @Ed Beal describes the sealant as being reusable, I wonder if that is what the blob of gray junk hanging off the wires on the right side is, and if you could just jam it back in the hole?

Comment: @izzy good idea but the material that is there looks like the kind that comes in a tube and drys I would be let that stuff is fairly hard. Monkey sh!t is like modeling clay.